EXPLAIN SQL does not use the index in GridDB
I have created an index, but explain sql does not use the index. I have ensured that GridDB has up-to-date statistics by running the available commands and index on (DeviceId, Property) is in the correct order.
griddb 5.1.0
gs[public]> explain analyze select * from properties_test where deviceId='101' and property='0' limit 0,10;
The query had been executed. (60,662 ms)
gs[public]> getplantxt
Id Type     Input Rows Lead time Actual time Node               And more..                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0 SCAN     -     -        60597       48739 192.168.1.62:10001 table: {properties_test} LIMIT: 10
 1   RESULT 0     10           0           0 192.168.1.62:20001                                   
gs[public]> showcontainer properties_test
Database    : public
Name        : properties_test
Type        : COLLECTION
Partition ID: 13
DataAffinity: -

Columns:
No  Name                  Type            CSTR  RowKey
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0  Type                  STRING                
 1  DeviceId              STRING                
 2  Property              STRING                
 3  Id                    STRING                
 4  NumberValue           DOUBLE                
 5  Value                 STRING                
 6  CreateTime            TIMESTAMP             
 7  Timestamp             TIMESTAMP             

Indexes:
Name        : 
Type        : TREE
Columns:
No  Name                  
--------------------------
 0  Property

Name        : 
Type        : TREE
Columns:
No  Name                  
--------------------------
 0  DeviceId

Name        : 
Type        : TREE
Columns:
No  Name                  
--------------------------
 0  Timestamp

Name        : 
Type        : TREE
Columns:
No  Name                  
--------------------------
 0  DeviceId
 1  Property

